# Consider the following section of abridged Java code, classes

Tags: java

> Consider the following section of abridged Java code:
>
> ```
> public class CashRegisterCheckout
>    {
>     ...
>        class ItemScanned extends JPanel
>        { 
>         ...
>        } // end class ItemScanned
>     ...
>     public double updateTransactionTotal(double itemPrice, int items)
>     {
>       ...
>       public int updateStock(int noItems)
>       {
>       ...
>       } // end updateStock
>     } // end updateTransactionTotal
> } // end class CashRegister
> ```
>
> Even though many lines of code are note shown above (i.e. lines
>   represented by “...” ) you should still be able to explain what is
>   wrong, in principle, with the code that is shown.

Right I've been given this question and I can see that the "public int updateStock(int noItems)" doesn't work when I test this but I can't give a real explanation as to why?

**I've done a search on here and looked into my text book.**

Could somebody please give me a simple explanation as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: Try to indent the code so it will be easier to spot the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a method within a method :

```
public double updateTransactionTotal(double itemPrice, int items)
{
...
public int updateStock(int noItems)
```

That's invalid syntax.